# Erro 500 ou 502 na chamada Ajax a um arquivo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, apache

Estou com  o seguinte problema, tenho uma tela de relatório que faz uma chamada Ajax que Retorna todos os itens pra mim. Porém quando o relatório tem poucos registros ele retorna tudo certinho, o Ajax faz a solicitação recebe a informação e joga na tela.
Porém quando a consulta retorna mais de 13 mil registro o método fica demorado, e o Ajax fica por alguns minutos processando, depois ocorre o erro 500 ou 502. 
Quando eu uso o Debug no método passando os mesmos parâmetros do Ajax, o método demora um pouco pra ser executado devido a quantidade de registros, porém o método chega ao final, já rodando no browser ele morre e da o erro 500 ou 502.

Alguém tem alguma solução alternativa ?

Comment: Execute esse arquivo do ajax direto e habilite os herros no php e veja qual é o real problema, deve ter algo relacionado com quantia de registros ...

Comment: aposto que uma pista está no log do apache.

Comment: LOG PHP deu a seguinte informação : [01-Feb-2016 11:47:43 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in C:/.....

Alguém já passou por isso antes ?

Comment: LOG APACHE : [Mon Feb 01 11:47:57.816753 2016] [core:error] [pid 3324:tid 972] [client 192.168.0.210:16290] End of script output before headers: retorna_metodo_ajax.php5, referer: http://192.168.0.210/manager/rel_relacao_cupons.php5

Alguém já passou por isso antes ?

Comment: Já passei, disse que não existe o indice 5 no array.

Comment: Tem mais ..
[Fri Jan 29 11:49:21.383525 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11640:tid 4] AH00362: Child: Waiting 30 more seconds for 3 worker threads to finish.
[Fri Jan 29 11:49:51.560937 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11640:tid 4] AH00362: Child: Waiting 0 more seconds for 3 worker threads to finish.
[Fri Jan 29 11:49:51.661375 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11640:tid 4] AH00363: Child: Terminating 3 threads that failed to exit.